# App Icon Only Changes After Device Reboot

Tags: ios, swift, icons, device

I am implementing custom app icons for my iOS app, and everything works in the simulator. But when I try on device I get errrors:

`+[LSApplicationProxy applicationProxyFor*] is not a supported method for getting the LSApplicationProxy for the current process, use +[LSBundleProxy bundleProxyForCurrentProcess] instead.`

`LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}`

`Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.`

`Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=264, _LSFunction=-[_LSDReadClient getServerStoreWithCompletionHandler:]}`

It shows a pop-up that the icon was changed, but the icon in the pop-up is empty, and the app's icon turns into the default white blank icon. Only after I reboot the phone, the icon displays correctly.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue now. This is strange as everything was working fine not too long ago. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @LukeIrvin Nope. In my case the issue only affects one device. Simulator and other devices switch icons properly. Hence I assume something is wrong with that particular phone.

Comment: Oh wow, very interesting. I'm seeing the issue on both the simulator and device.

Comment: I have the same issue, but only on iPads. iPhones do change the icon as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case issue was only showing up on one particular device. After I changed the app's bundle identifier, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution looking into Apples example project:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring_your_app_to_use_alternate_app_icons

Take a look into the Build-Settings:
[image]

You need to set the Alternate App Icons Sets as references here.

After you've built the app, you can check out the generated *Info.plist* inside the "AlternateAppIcon.app" file (right click "Show Package content").

You can now see the format of the the top-level keys **CFBundleIcons** and **CFBundleIcons~ipad**. The entries under the key **CFBundleAlternateIcons** contain the references to the alternative icons.

I used this as a blue-print for my projects *Info.plist* and now it is working again. Both on iPhone and iPad.